# Airflow (MWAA) tasks receiving SIGTERM but task is externally set to success

Tags: airflow, mwaa

We face a lot of our Airflow (MWAA) tasks receiving `SIGTERM`:

```
[2022-10-06 06:23:48,347] {{logging_mixin.py:104}} INFO - [2022-10-06 06:23:48,347] {{local_task_job.py:188}} WARNING - State of this instance has been externally set to success. Terminating instance.
[2022-10-06 06:23:48,348] {{process_utils.py:100}} INFO - Sending Signals.SIGTERM to GPID 2740
[2022-10-06 06:23:55,113] {{taskinstance.py:1265}} ERROR - Received SIGTERM. Terminating subprocesses.
[2022-10-06 06:23:55,164] {{process_utils.py:66}} INFO - Process psutil.Process(pid=2740, status='terminated', exitcode=1, started='06:23:42') (2740) terminated with exit code 1
```

It happens to a few of our tasks and it would not have been a big deal if the tasks were not set as a `SUCCESS`:

`State of this instance has been externally set to success. Terminating instance`

We understood that this can happen because of a lack of memory within the worker. We tried to increase the number of workers without any success. What would be our solutions to avoid having set tasks externally killed?

Answer (score 0):

When tasks are getting killed, they are marked as failed. Here it seems to be the other way around. The task seem to get marked by something/someone as a success, after which the job is stopped/killed.

I am not aware of how Mwaa is deployed, but I would have a look at the action logging to see what/who is marking these tasks as success.

Comment: There is no reason why the dag could be marked as a success by another task or another person. It happens with standalone tasks that have no interaction with others and I am 100% sure that noone marked them as a success from the UI/CLI. Could it be related to the fact that my tasks have no return value ?